# Grails STS project wont launch web service

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to launch a grails project from STS. The output gets to:

```
Environment set to test
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\dcole\.grails\1.3.7\projects\SkillsDB\classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\dcole\.grails\1.3.7\projects\SkillsDB
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\dcole\.grails\1.3.7\projects\SkillsDB\tomcat
Running Grails application..
```

And never starts the service. i dont see any tomcat or anything running, and navigating to localhost:8080 gives me nothing. i tried to change the grails port to 8090 and got nothing as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it working for a fresh grails project?

If not, this must be a firewall issue. Try to deactivate the firewall or allow javaw to open a socket on port 8080 and verify that you have launched your eclipse with admin rights.

If yes, then check your bootstrap. This might be absolutely application specific.

Comment: I tried that I think. Would it be an inbound rule in Windows Firewall settings?